# How to setup LDAP (RBAC) in Airflow?

Tags: ldap, airflow, rbac

The current issues I am having is that LDAP settings do not seem to work with Airflow. My current code does not produce a login screen nor are there logs in the docker container that shows it is attempting to connect to the LDAP server. I have attempted to follow these tutorials but they appear to do nothing (i.e. the `webserver_config.py` is not being used) [TutorialOne](https://itsecureadmin.com/2019/02/apache-airflow-1-10-2-active-directory-authentication-via-ldaps/) [TutorialTwo](https://guptakumartanuj.wordpress.com/2019/11/14/airflow-ui-authentication-through-ldap-server/)

Any information regarding how the connection works would be greatly appreciated!

`webserver_config.py`:

```
import os
from airflow import configuration as conf
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_LDAP
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = conf.get('core', 'SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN')

CSRF_ENABLED = True

AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_LDAP

AUTH_ROLE_ADMIN = 'Admin'
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True

AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Admin"
#AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Viewer"

AUTH_LDAP_SERVER = 'ldapserveraddressherebutIwon'tshowyousorry'
AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH =  "***"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_USER = '***'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD ="*******************"
AUTH_LDAP_UID_FIELD = 'sAMAccountName'
AUTH_LDAP_USE_TLS = False
AUTH_LDAP_ALLOW_SELF_SIGNED = False
# Get relative path for CA certificate file
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
AUTH_LDAP_TLS_CACERTFILE = script_dir + "ca.cer"
```

I have deleted the `authenticate = True` and `auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.ldap_auth` from `airflow.cfg` and my `webserver_config.py` is in the same folder for use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved through the `airflow.cfg`.

Please read the LDAP section below and let me know.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/security.html

Comment: Thanks for that link. Unfortunately I've gone through that page and the [page specifically for RBAC](https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html). If possible, I'd like to start with having the login page actually show up in the first place when Airflow spins up with Docker but this does not occur when the webserver_config.py file exists.

Comment: have you set this on your airflow.cfg [webserver]
authenticate = True
auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.ldap_auth

Comment: Also we use 1.10.10 and we dont use any webserver_config.py in our end. Can you just remove that file and try with airflow documentation. That should be enough as per my  experience.

Comment: I'll re-add authenticate = True and auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.ldap_auth. We're on 1.10.9 for Celery exe but I believe it should be the same.

Comment: I'll also remove the webserver_config.py and git it a go, thanks for your advice!

Comment: Would you also tell me how you used your CA certificate file? Is it within your Airflow repo or on the server which you're running Airflow?

Comment: Can you please accept my answer. If you want me to edit I will do so. Yes you need to add the ca certificate to your volume which should be readable by airflow and then use that path in the airflow.cfg. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: You have couple of options for your CA. You can keep it in a vault and bring it to your docker volume. Or you can keep it in a repo if that is ok with your organization.

Comment: I just add it as cacert in the ldap section of airflow.cfg. Try that up.