# Airflow + OpenLDAP

Tags: airflow, devops, openldap

Please help me set up OpenLDAP Authentication in Airflow. I have been unable to solve the problem for two days. My system is running on Ubuntu 18.04. Here's what my configuration looks like:

In airflow.cfg file, I have deleted `[Webserver] authentication = True` and all `[LDAP]`. I have also updated `rbac` field from `rbac = False` to `rbac = True`.

I create a file `webserver_config.py` that includes the following lines of code:

```
import os
from airflow import configuration as conf
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_LDAP
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_LDAP
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER = "ldap://192.168.1.31:389"
AUTH_LDAP_USE_TLS = False
AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH = "dc=test,dc=com"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_USER = "dc=admin,dc=test,dc=com"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "123456"
```

In my case, the logs say that there is a connection, but when I try to connect, it says that I entered the wrong username or password.

Comment: Check if this SO link helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63305007/how-to-setup-ldap-rbac-in-airflow/63305715#63305715

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, but forgot to post it. In the airflow.cfg file, change the [ldap] line to this

```
[ldap]
# set this to ldaps://<your.ldap.server>:<port>
uri = ldap://192.168.1.20:389
user_filter = objectClass=*
user_name_attr = uid
group_member_attr = memberUid
superuser_filter =
data_profiler_filter =
bind_user = cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com
bind_password = 123456
basedn = ou=Peoples,dc=test,dc=com
cacert = /etc/ca/ldap_ca.crt
# search_scope = LEVEL
```